# Appending options to select using JQuery

Tags: php, json, jquery, symfony

I have two select dropdowns where the options of the 2nd select box needs to be changed according to the 1st select. The form is

```
<form action="" method="post" >
        <div style="padding-bottom:6px;">
            <select id="portfolios" name="portfolio" style="width: 200px; height:25px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="default">Select Portfolio</option>
                {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
                    <option get-groups="{{ path('v2_pm_patents_getgroups') }}" value={{ portfolio.id }}>{{ portfolio.portfolioName }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <span>OR</span>
            <a class="modalbox1" href="#inline1">[Add New Portfolio]</a>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-bottom:6px; display:none;" id="groups">
            <select id="portfolio-groups" name="portfolio-groups" style="width:200px; height:25px;">
                <option selected="selected" value="default">Select Portfolio Group</option>
            </select>
            <span> OR</span>
            <a class="modalbox2" href="#inline2">[Add New Group]</a>
        </div>
</form>
```

Initially the 2nd dropdown is hidden when I select an option from the 1st select it becomes visible.
The JQuery I wrote is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#portfolios').change(function() {
            $('#groups').show();
            var id = $("#portfolios").val();
            var url = $('option:selected', this).attr("get-groups");
            var data = {PID:id};
            $.getJSON(url, data, function(result) {
                var options = $("#portfolio-groups");
                $.each(result, function(item) {
                    options.append($("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.name));
                });
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

My Controller method which I call is

```
public function getgroupsAction(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $id = $request->get("PID");
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $portfolio_groups = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPatentgroups')
        ->getpatentgroups($id);
        echo json_encode($portfolio_groups);
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

I get the correct groups from my query and in JSon Object. The Object in response looks like

```
[{"id":"09c0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2","name":"Group 2","description":"No Description Provided for this Group","order":500000,"is_deleted":false}]
```

In my JQuery I append options to select box but the problem is it appends the options but with empty value atribute and no text. So neither the text nor the value attribute is visible just empty options are added.

What I am doing wrong? and How can I clear the select box before appending options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(item.id) inside the $.each call to see if you are accessing the right values?

Comment: will give it a try in an hour will let you know

Comment: item.id and item.name both are undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting your JSON response wrapped inside an array. Try accessing your elements inside `$.each` like this `item[0].name` and `item[0].id`

Then you'd need to account for getting multiple objects and loop over the item array

Comment: How can i loop over it if I dont know the length?

Comment: This is the response I get [{"id":"04d0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2","name":"Group 1","description":"Description of Patent Group 1","order":56250000,"is_deleted":false},{"id":"9d4f6e5c-dd73-11e1-bed3-fbfe082dc761","name":"Group 3","description":"Description of Patent Group 3","order":70312500,"is_deleted":false},{"id":"06d0d4b2-ac25-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2","name":"Group 2","description":"Description of Patent Group 2","order":84375000,"is_deleted":false}]

Comment: You should know the length, result.length  Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a24LT/

Comment: if you look at my JQuery I used $.getJSON(url, data, function(result)... Do i need this If i go with your solution or not ?

Comment: I have exactly the same data in my response but when I alert it instead of giving 4 it gives me 572... This is what I am doing... $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: data,
     url:url,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
      alert(data.length);
     }
     });

Comment: if I alert only data it gives me the correct response that you put in the result variable

Comment: Try to access at least the first item inside the $.each call to see what happens, if you put console.log(item[0].name); do you get anything?

Comment: Your solution as almost correct but additionally I needed to to parse my JSON String to array success: function(data) { var myArray = JSON.parse(data); var options = $("#portfolio-groups"); for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ options.append($("<option />").val(myArray[i].id).text(myArray[i].name)); } }

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `.val()` in this case. You have to use `.attr("value",item.id)`

Comment: You could use `val` to set a value of input elements like input text, textarea or select. But you can't use it to set an attribute like in case of `option` value attrubute.

Comment: because val() is not made for setting the value attribute of an element. It is rather made for setting the value of a select element by marking the option element with the desired value as selected

Comment: I agree with @MarieLuise I've used this syntax before to add options like this http://jsfiddle.net/yhf4S/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explaination I will give it a try soon, but no body answered my 2nd question regarding clearing the select before appending options

Comment: To remove all options $("#groups option").remove();  to remove a specific one $("#groups option[value='0']").remove();

Comment: I tried this options.append($("<option />").attr("value",item.id).attr("text",item.name)); still not showing anything just adding empty options

Answer (score 0):

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xYbWC/2/)

```
$("#mSelect").append($("<option />").val('1').text('-- Select --'));

var myOptions = response.d;
                var mySelect = $("#MainContent_ddlnewType");
                mySelect.children().remove();
                //mySelect.append($("<option>").val("00").text("-- Select Type --"));
                for (var i = 0; i < myOptions.length; i++) {
                    var val = myOptions[i].Id;
                    var text = myOptions[i].Name;
                    mySelect.append($("<option>").val(val).text(text));
                }
```

Comment: `var data.result = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
];

$.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
    alert(data.result[i].PageName);
});​`

Comment: in your case you only need resonse,is hold a json data

Comment: By the way myOptions is undefined